# Extract element from associative array

Tags: php

How do I extract an element from an associative array?

```
$array = array(
   "smart" => "dog",
   "stupid" => "cat",
   "nasty" => "frog",
   "big" => "elephant"
);
```

I need to remove the element with key "nasty" to push it in the end of the array. I don't know the index of the element in the array. How can I achieve this? (I'm using first, second, third but the names of the keys are different and not indexed by a logic! I need to remove the element just by its key).

Comment: An associative array doesn't really have an "end".  Are you sure this wouldn't work better with a non-associative array?

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Watch the example now: I need push the element in a certain order because I'm printing the array with a json_encode.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$array = array(
   "first" => "un",
   "second" => "dos",
   "third" => "tres"
);

$second = $array['second'];
unset($array['second']);
$array['second'] = $second;
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["first"]=>
  string(2) "un"
  ["third"]=>
  string(4) "tres"
  ["second"]=>
  string(3) "dos"
}
```

**Edit**

```
$array = array(
   "first" => "un",
   "second" => "dos",
   "third" => "tres"
);
$output = array();

$order = array('first', 'third', 'second');
foreach ( $order as $key ) {
    if ( isset($output[$key]) ) {
        $output[$key] = $array[$key];
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting! But I have 35 fields to order... I'll put this in a function to use just one line for each element.

Comment: I'll post a second way to do it.

Comment: the key names doesn't mean the order in that way. Give a look at the example now! Anyway thanks for help, I'm trying to put the first method in a function but it seems to not work.

Comment: function queueElementByKey($array, $key)
{
   $temp = $array[$key];
   unset($array[$key]);
   $array[$key] = $temp;
   return $array;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(
   "smart" => "dog",
   "stupid" => "cat",
   "nasty" => "frog",
   "big" => "elephant"
);

$array += array_splice($array, array_search('nasty', array_keys($array)), 1);

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `extract($array);`?